# Trying to set up a systemd service, keep getting "changing to the requested working directory failed: permission denied"

Tags: permissions, java, systemd, minecraft

I've new to Linux, only switched around 4 months ago from Windows. I'm trying to install a Minecraft server using [this](https://bobcares.com/blog/install-minecraft-server-on-ubuntu/) tutorial, and I keep getting this when I try to start the server through systemd and check the status of it:

```
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/minecraft.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-07-19 22:32:20 PDT; 6s ago
    Process: 21308 ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar server.jar nogui (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)
   Main PID: 21308 (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)
        CPU: 14ms

Jul 19 22:32:20 myname-ThinkPad systemd[1]: Started Minecraft Server.
Jul 19 22:32:20 myname-ThinkPad systemd[21308]: minecraft.service: Changing to the requested working directory failed: Permission denied
Jul 19 22:32:20 myname-ThinkPad systemd[21308]: minecraft.service: Failed at step CHDIR spawning /usr/bin/java: Permission denied
Jul 19 22:32:20 myname-ThinkPad systemd[1]: minecraft.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=200/CHDIR
Jul 19 22:32:20 myname-ThinkPad systemd[1]: minecraft.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I did deviate from the tutorial in a couple spots, and I'm sure that's where the problem is. I used my own user profile to install the server instead of making a separate one, for a couple of reasons, but I made sure to change the paths accordingly. I also had to install Oracle Java, because OpenJDK was having issues installing the server file (I used 1.19 instead of 1.16, which is the one linked in the tutorial).

Here's the systemd file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Minecraft Server
After=network.target

[Service]
User=myname
Nice=1
KillMode=none
SuccessExitStatus=0 1
ProtectHome=true
ProtectSystem=full
PrivateDevices=true
NoNewPrivileges=true
WorkingDirectory=/home/myname/mc_server/server
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar server.jar nogui
ExecStop=/home/myname/mc_server/tools/mcrcon/mcrcon -H 127.0.0.1 -P 25575 -p serverpasswd stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

So I guess my question is, is there any way to fix this without having to make a separate user profile or going back to OpenJDK (and by extension, an older version of the game)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you set `ProtectHome=true`, which restricts the service's access to `/home`, but also want the service to `cd` to `/home`. It can't do that, since it is set to `ProtectHome`, and therefore it gives you the error you see:

```
Changing to the requested working directory failed: Permission denied
```

The solution to this is to either:

1. put the Minecraft files in `/opt`, as the tutorial says or
2. remove the `ProtectHome` line from the service file in order to allow the service access to `/home`.

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed everything.